# GTA V starts in Online Mode

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I finished story mode in GTA V and now when I start the game I have only the option to START IN Online mode.

Is there any way to continue story mode from the point I finished? I love to move in roads etc.

Also, the way it autostarts is very annoying.

Comment: Do you mean GTA 4 or 5? What platform are you playing on?

Comment: i have gta 5 on ps3

Comment: The game should be starting in single player, giving you an option(the only other option) to start tbe game in online mode(pressing x or square or something).

Comment: Try loading not connected to the internet if that is the case and check the option menu within singleplayer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change your character in online mode to one of the 3 from story. After this, your game will switch to story mode. You should be able to play in story mode for as long as you want.

Also, when the game start to load online mode, you should be able to switch with a button (I don't remember which one but it should be shown on loading screen).

Comment: The X button. You have to be quick(ish) though. The option doesn't appear immediately when loading, and then disappears a while later before it finishes loading.